# ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package whilst referring within same app

Tags: django, importerror

I am here because google search didn't solve the issue yet.

Django Version 4.0.6

Project structure created in Visual Studio Community 2022 is like as follows,

```
Project0
|
--Project0
|
---settings.py
--- <>
|
--App1
|
---models.py
---views.py
---forms.py
|
--App2
|
---models.py
---views.py
---forms.py
---tables.py
```

Project0, App1, App2 are all in same hierarchy.

When trying to run the solution, I am getting the following errors with App2 files,

```
File "D:\Projects\Django\Project0\App2\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "D:\Projects\Django\Project0\App2\views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .tables import ProductTable, ProductHTMXtable
  File "D:\Projects\Django\Project0\App2\tables.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..App1.models import List
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

1st issue:
Here in App2 there are no models created. Instead, importing models from App1's model. So I guess the line --> from ..App1.models import List <-- might be wrong. If I remove those 2 dots '..' then I get Import could not be resolved error and the models are not being referred though its not stopping the solution from running.

2nd issue:
Why do --> from . import views <-- & --> from .tables import <-- too are throwing errors.

Unable to fix theses issues. Please help.

Answering to Balizok: If I do so I am getting not resolved error as attached here.
[App1Model could not be resolved error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOYGr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Import using `from App1.models import List` instead of `from ..App1.models import List` and that should do it.

As it is now, you're going, as the error suggests, beyond top-level package by using the `..App1`, where refering to the app name doesn't.

Comment: Balizok, thanks! I did that too, but I am getting could not be resolved issue, and so the view is not working in bringing up data from the table. (Attached image of error in question) Any help?

Comment: And if you try to run the server the `not resolved` error is still here ? Sometimes this error shows in the IDE while still working. I tried doing the same type of import in my project and my solution worked perfectly so that may be it.

Comment: Runserver is working but the model is not getting loaded. The model name 'List' after import is not shown in green color like that of 'TextInput' (referring attached image). But when I used double dots '..' it was shown in green color but runserver didn't work. In both ways the solution is not working bringing in expected result. Any help please?

Comment: guessing bug with Django Version 4.0.6 ?

Comment: I've no idea why it wouldn't work, since that worked for me that's probably not a syntax error, but I don't think of anything that would help you, sorry